# When testing an Angular service, how would I mock a controller using that service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an Angular service that is used by different controllers.  It contains a method that expects any controller instance as argument.

```
myService.methodAbc( ctrl );
```

I know how to set up the Jasmine specs for the service but I am at a loss when it comes to setting up a fake controller in my specs so I can test said method.  Using one of the app's existing controllers feels wrong as my service's test would break were I to rename/change/delete the controller.

Any input would be appreciated.  I have the feeling I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a plain-old object to act as a fake controller. Personally, I prefer to use [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/) to create stubs for methods, because it will allow your test to assert how, say, `myService` interacts with `ctrl`. Jasmine has its own fake object methods, which I am not familiar with which you can use as well. Here's how it would look when using SinonJS ([and a library which integrates it with Jasmine](https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon)):

```
var fakeController = {
    someMethod: sinon.stub(), 
    anotherMethod: sinon.stub() 
};
myService.methodAbc(fakeController);

expect(fakeController.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', 'bar');
```

**Update:**

Here's how you can use the native Jasmine library to do the same:

```
var fakeController = jasmine.createSpyObj(
    'fakeController', 
    ['someMethod', 'anotherMethod']);

myService.methodAbc(fakeController);

expect(fakeController.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: I was right, I *was* missing something obvious.  Thank you!